# String declaration in C w/r/t memory

Tags: c, memory, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

I'm trying to better understand how different methods of declaring strings in c translate to different types of memory allocation.

Bus errors occur when attempting to modify *some* strings, but not others. Whether or not an error occurs clearly depends on the way the string being modified is declared, but I don't feel I have a robust understanding of why. More specifically, I don't understand where actual characters are stored when a string literal is assigned to a char*. Here's a simple test example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int stack_var = 5;
  char* str1 = "This is a string.";
  char str2[17] = "This is a string.";
  char* heap_str = malloc(18);
  strcpy(heap_str, "This is a string.");

  printf("\n addresses: %p, %p, %p, %p, %p", &stack_var, str1, &str1, str2, heap_str);

  int option = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (option == 1) {
    str1[5] = '\0';          //   Bus error
  } else if (option == 2) {
    str2[5] = '\0';          //   No problem
  } else if (option==3) {
    heap_str[5] = '\0';      //   No problem
  }
}
```

On an arbitrary run on my computer, here's the address printout:
`addresses: 0x7ff7be6f585c, 0x10180df66, 0x7ff7be6f5850, 0x7ff7be6f5870, 0x600002129120%`

Although str1, str2, and heap_str all resolve to the same string, the addresses make several differences clear:

1. str2 points to a sequence of chars stored in the stack.
2. The address of str1 is a location in the stack; str1 is stored in the stack as a pointer, only.
3. The character sequence pointed to by str1 is *not* in the stack.
4. The character sequence pointed to by str1 doesn't look like it's in the heap, either.

So my question boils down to this: where are the characters pointed to by str1 stored?

I'm guessing (hoping) that the answer clarifies why that sequence of characters cannot be modified, while the stack and heap versions of the same can be.

I'm new to c, so apologies for any conspicuous naivety. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing: Do you know about the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of a program?

Comment: Haven't read it all, but `char str2[17] = "This is a string.";` should be `char str2[18] = "This is a string.";`. You need space for the null terminator.

Comment: @AviBerger Honestly should be `char str[] = "..."`.

Comment: ... or `char str2[] = "This is a string.";`, which will right-size the array automatically to exactly the space required to store the initializer.

Comment: `str1` can be in the .text segment or the .rodata segment or anywhere else the compiler wants to put it. All you know is that attempting to modify it will result in undefined behavior. In other words, it might work, it might not.

Comment: @tadman Yes, it is better to let the compiler count for you. OP is counting chars though and uses 18 on the next line for malloc, so seems to be missing the point that a null terminator is also needed in the automatic array.

Comment: @AviBerger Yep thanks, 17 was a mistake. Interesting that the string prints out just fine even when declared that way.

Comment: It's an accident if the string actually prints out fine. Also, as @tadman and John Bollinger commented, `char str[] = "..."` is definitely a better way of doing it: you don't have to count the characters, you don't have the potential of getting it wrong by miscounting, and it doesn't become an error when you have to edit the string literal later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char* str1 = "This is a string.";
```

you declared a pointer to a string literal. Though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change a string literal like you are trying to do

```
str1[5] = '\0';
```

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior,

String literals have static storage duration. Their lifetimes do not depend on in which block scope they are used. Usually compilers store string literals in literal pools.

The pointer `str1` itself has automatic storage duration.

In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays. So in C++ you have to write

```
const char* str1 = "This is a string.";
```

It is a good practice to declare pointers to string literals in C also with the qualifier `const`.

In this declaration

```
char str2[17] = "This is a string.";
```

you allocated an array with automatic storage duration. The array does not contain a string because it does not have a space to accommodate the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal used as an initializer.

In C++ such a declaration is invalid.

In this declaration

```
char* heap_str = malloc(18);
```

you allocated dynamically a memory for a character array. The array will have allocated storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Newbies to C often fail to recognize or grasp the differences between a "string", a "string *literal*", an "array of `char`", and a "pointer to `char`".  Those are four distinct things.

- an *array of `char`* is an object (thus having associated storage) that can contain a specific, positive, number of `char` values.
- a *string* is a sequence of one or more `char` values, the last of which is a null character (`'\0'`).  This is a kind of *value* that an array of `char` can contain, but it is not itself an array, and the value stored in an array of `char` is not necessarily of this form.
- a *string literal* is a lexeme in C source code that, when used as an lvalue, represents an array of `char` with static storage duration and the contents specified by the literal, null-terminated.  The storage for these is not guaranteed to be disjoint (that is, multiple appearances of the same literal might represent the same storage), and undefined behavior results from attempts to modify the contents of the array.
- a *pointer to `char`* is exactly what the name says.  **If** the pointer is valid, then the character to which it points might be the first in a (null-terminated) string, but it does not have to be.

It gets a bit more muddied, however, because (roughly speaking) whenever an array-valued expression is evaluated the (array) result is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element.  This is why all the string functions accept with `char *` arguments, and why you can assign a string literal to a variable of type `char *` (or better, `const char *`).  This does not mean that you should conflate pointers with strings.

Thus, here:

> ```
>   char* str1 = "This is a string.";
> ```

`str1` is initialized to point to the first `char` in the array represented by the string literal.  That array has static storage duration, and attempting to modify its contents produces undefined behavior.

> So my question boils down to this: where are the characters pointed to by str1 stored?

C does not say.  More generally, the C language specification does not divide memory into different types or areas at all.  Different C *implementations* often do that, but that's a separate question, and it has to be addressed per implementation.

It is entirely possible that a particular C implementation stores string literals' values in memory marked read-only (by some system specific means), such that attempts to modify them fail.  For this reason, it is usually recommended that you avoid causing pointers of type `char *` to point to the values of string literals.  Using type `const char *` instead, and making sure to preserve `const`ness as you work with those and pass them around, can ensure that you avoid attempting to modify string literals.

Comment: Very helpful. I was thrown by something I read (or perhaps misunderstood) somewhere that defined all double-quoted strings in c as string literals. In that sense, the right side of both of these assignments would be a string literal:

char str[] = "This is a string.";
char* str = "This is a string.";

but only the second example writes a string literal as such to addressable memory, where in the first example the string expression is just used to initialize the char array. Is it meaningful or accurate to refer to "This is a string" in the first example as a string literal?

Comment: @chvolow24, for the sake of precision, in both of those cases, the language spec calls `"This is a string"` is a string literal, though personally, I do tend to think of it as merely an initializer.  Anyway, in the array case, the the characters of the literal are used to initialize an independent array, whereas in the pointer case, the pointer is initialized to point to the array that the literal itself represents.